Defining Unsupervised Learning Problem
I have read a paper that says

Unsupervised learning concerns modeling and understanding the structure of complex data ...
Of course, the distribution over such complex data as images and sounds cannot be mathematically specified, but we often have access to an empirical distribution of $\textbf{P}$ samples:
$$q(x)=\frac{1}{P}\sum_{i=1}^{P}\delta(x-x^i).$$
For example, each $x^i$ could denote a vector of pixel intensities for images, or a time series of pressure variations for sound.
The goal of unsupervised learning is to adjust the parameters $\textbf{w}$ of a family of distributions $\textbf{p(x; w)}$ to find one similar to the data distribution $\textbf{q(x)}$. This is often done by maximizing the log likelihood of the data with respect to model parameters $\textbf{w}$:
$$l(x)=\int dx \ q(x)\cdot log(p(x; w)) $$
This learning principle modifies $\textbf{p}$ to assign high probability to data points, and consequently low probability elsewhere, thereby moving the model distribution, $\textbf{p(x;w)}$, closer to the data distribution, $\textbf{q(x)}$.

My question is very simple: Why introduce $\textbf{q(x)}$ and why is it defined as sum of differences with sampled vectors? To maximize our understanding of data distribution, isn't maximizing
$$l(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{P} log(p(x^i; w))$$
already enough? Or, if we want integral, maximizing
$$l(x)=\int_{\{x_i\}} dx \ log(p(x; w)) $$
would make more sense for me.
